# Using Dates in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to using PL/SQL and I have created a procedure but I cannot figure out the correct syntax in order to get the current month and year's data and another cursor to get the data from exactly 1 year prior:

```
create or replace procedure data(acc integer, month integer, year integer)
as


Cursor c1 is 
select usage
from bill
where account =acc_num and to_char(BILL_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') = 'month-year';


Cursor c3 is 
select usage
from bill
where account =acc_num and
     to_char(BILL_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') = 'month-year' - 1;
```

** I do understand this is only part of the code, but I believe my logic is almost complete for finding the data I want. Using PLSQL

Comment: It's the same syntax as in plain SQL and you already have an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select usage
from bill
where account = in_account and
      extract(year from bill_date) = in_year and
      extract(month from bill_date) = in_month;
```

If you want to compare the year and month (which are passed in as integers), just extract those attributes from the date.

If you are learning PL/SQL, learn to name your parameters and arguments so you can distinguish them from columns:

```
create or replace procedure data (
    in_account integer,
    in_month integer,
    in_year integer
) as
begin
    . . .
```

(And "data" is a very curious name for a stored procedure.  I would expect a verb in the name.)

Comment: so you would just do like in_year-1?? i am not understanding how to subtract one year

Comment: To get the previous year, you would use `in_year - 1`.  `in_year` is an integer (such as 2,016).